# Constantly Update UI in Java FX worker thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-2, task

I have `Label label` in my FXML Application.

I want this label to change once a second. Currently I use this:

```
        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {
            int i = 0;
            while (true) {
                lbl_tokenValid.setText(""+i);
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
```

However nothing is happening.

I don't get any errors or exceptions.
I don't need the value I change the label to in my main GUI thread so I don't see the point in the `updateMessage` or `updateProgress` methods.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

you need to make changes to the scene graph on the JavaFX UI thread.
like this:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
  @Override
  public Void call() throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      final int finalI = i;
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          label.setText("" + finalI);
        }
      });
      i++;
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }
};
Thread th = new Thread(task);
th.setDaemon(true);
th.start();
```

Comment: Studying your example helped me understand the JavaFX concurrency better. Thanks a ton.

Comment: I included this code in initialize() method but i'm getting Null pointer exception at the line "label.setText("" + finalI);"

Comment: @user1335906 make sure that your label is set in the fxml file.

Comment: where do you put this code snippet? ButtonAction? Main? Extra class?
Which type of Task should i use? There are multiple "Task" declarations in  JavaFX

Comment: When i do `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId())` inside `call()` it prints the same id as in `main`. Is this normal?

Comment: I have the same problem. But it doesn't solve my problem. It prints all logs print fire event after all process is done.

Answer (score 14):

Cosmetic change to Sebastian's code.

```
 while (true)
 {
   final int finalI = i++;
   Platform.runLater ( () -> label.setText ("" + finalI));
   Thread.sleep (1000);
 }
```

Comment: this is far more important than a cosmetic change as it allows for easy variable passing.
this is the more correct method.