# stop for X seconds before running next function in JAVA FXML (using SCENEBUILDER)

Tags: javafx, controller, fxml, thread-sleep, fxmlloader

I've used Scenebuilder to place few shapes in my GUI (simplified version of my project). I would like the shapes to change colours but wait 2 seconds between changing colours. I want these changes to happen in my controller class after a button is pressed.

```
Circle1.setFill(YELLOW)
Wait(2 seconds)
Circle2.setFill(BLUE)
```

I'm not sure how to do that. I have read online about threading, but I don't really understand how to implement that from my Main and into my Controller class. Also, I could not really find any examples online. My Main class looks like:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = (BorderPane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("File.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();    
    }
}
```

Please help. Also, if you could provide an example would be helpful for me to understand as I could not really find one online that gives an example of this.

Comment: First of all your code above is not your controller instead I see your main class ( correct me if i am wrong ). Now i would suggest to actually get the fxml's controller and each time the button is been pressed to call a method inside your controller making the changes. To add a delay on changes you would need to make a task wrapped on a Runnable.runLater call cause you are making changes to the UI. Right now I am not to a PC to provide you an example so you will have to wait for someone else.

Comment: Ah yes, a typo infact. I have changed that now. For my project I have to do several things that autonomously change with a delay of few seconds. So it will be practical for me to attempt to create that task. Just to clarify, is that task Runnable.runLater call created in the Controller or Main? If its in the Main, how do I reference to it in the Controller.

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497845/constantly-update-ui-in-java-fx-worker-thread of course you can create your task inside your controller or in your main..it's up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering this question is easiest through an example I believe. So I've created a small Traffic Light application, since it allows me to use `Circle` and a timed sequence similar to your problem, whilst being a familiar concept for all.

I'll be using `java.util.Timer` alongside `java.util.TimerTask` for handling the sequence of lights. You may choose to use some animation / time line in JavaFX, but I think that is overkill for this kind of task.

I include the three files used in this project:

- `FXMLTrafficLight.fxml` - which defines my FXML layout
- `FXMLTrafficLightController.java` - my FXML controller
- `TrafficLightApplication.java` - for completeness my subclass of `Application`, this is just the boiler plate.

**FXMLTrafficLight.fxml**

Not a fancy layout, just a `VBox` with three circles `redLight`, `amberLight` and `greenLight`, plus two `Button` objects `startLights` and `stopLights` used to start and stop the timer.

```
<VBox fx:id="root" id="VBox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxtimer.FXMLTrafficLightController">
    <children>
        <Circle fx:id="redLight" radius="100"></Circle>
        <Circle fx:id="amberLight" radius="100"></Circle>
        <Circle fx:id="greenLight" radius="100"></Circle>
        <Button fx:id="startLights" text="Start Lights" onAction="#startLights"></Button>
        <Button fx:id="stopLights" text="Start Lights" onAction="#stopLights"></Button>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

**FXMLTrafficLightController.java**

I've included the model/state in the controller for simplicity. Whether a light is red / amber / green is determined by a `boolean` flag. The initial state is set in the `initialize()` method, and is updated by calling `updateState()`.

When `startLights(ActionEvent)` is invoked (the `EventHandler` for `startLights`) a new `Timer` is constructed with a `TimerTask` implementation that first invokes `updateState()` on the thread created by the `Timer` and then invokes `updateLights()` which changes the color of the lights based on the current state on the JavaFX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater(Runnable)`.

Note: the `TimerTask` itself will not be run on the JavaFX Application Thread, hence the need to use `Platform.runLater(Runnable)` for updating the GUI.

When `stopLights(ActionEvent)` is invoked, it will cancel the `Timer`.

Note that both `startLights(ActionEvent)` and `stopLights(ActionEvent)` toggle which `Button` objects are enabled on the interface as well.

```
public class FXMLTrafficLightController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Circle redLight;

    @FXML
    private Circle amberLight;

    @FXML
    private Circle greenLight;

    @FXML
    private Button startLights;

    @FXML
    private Button stopLights;

    private Timer timer;
    private static final int DELAY = 2000; // ms

    private boolean red, amber, green;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        red = true;
        amber = false;
        green = false;
        stopLights.setDisable(true);
        updateLights();
    }

    @FXML
    private void startLights(ActionEvent e) {
        toggleButtons();
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Not run on the JavaFX Application Thread!
                updateState();
                // Using Platform.runLater(Runnable) to ensure updateLights()
                // is run on the JavaFX Application Thread
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateLights();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, DELAY); // no initial delay, trigger again every 2000 ms (DELAY)
    }

    @FXML
    private void stopLights(ActionEvent e) {
        toggleButtons();
        timer.cancel();        
    }

    private void toggleButtons() {        
        startLights.setDisable(!startLights.isDisable());
        stopLights.setDisable(!stopLights.isDisable());
    }

    private void updateState() {
        if (red && !amber && !green) {
            amber = true;
        } else if (red && amber && !green) {
            red = false;
            amber = false;
            green = true;
        } else if (!red && !amber && green) {
            green = false;
            amber = true;
        } else {
            red = true;
            amber = false;
            green = false;
        }
    }

    private void updateLights() {
        redLight.setFill(red ? Color.RED : Color.GREY);
        amberLight.setFill(amber ? Color.ORANGE : Color.GREY);
        greenLight.setFill(green ? Color.GREEN : Color.GREY);
    }
}
```

**TrafficLightApplication.java**

For completeness... Just the standard boiler plate with file names changed.

```
public class TrafficLightApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLTrafficLight.fxml"));        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);        
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much!! That's actually very helpful!!